# jenkins-1.489 maven-3.0.3 & sonar-3.3.1

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have upgraded Sonar to version 3.3.1 from 3.0.1,
and my code analisys jobs has been broken.

all projects with code analisys jobs are multimodule maven projects with hierarchical structure

on previous version of sonar (3.0.1), job was configured with one maven build step:

```
org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.0.1:sonar -P sonar -X
```

(sonar server information is stored in maven profile named "sonar")

now i've changed the this build step to

```
org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3._3_.1:sonar -P sonar -X
```

and now builds are failing.

Does anyone know the solution ?

There is a stackTrace:

```
    6:48:21 Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
    16:48:21 mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
    16:48:21 message : Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.3.1:sonar (default-cli) on project proj-parent: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.3.1:sonar failed: null value
    16:48:21 cause : Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.3.1:sonar failed: null value
    16:48:21 Stack trace : 
    16:48:21 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.3.1:sonar (default-cli) on project proj-parent: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.3.1:sonar failed: null value
    16:48:21    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    16:48:21    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    16:48:21    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    16:48:21    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    16:48:21    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    16:48:21    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    16:48:21    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    16:48:21    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    16:48:21    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    16:48:21    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    16:48:21    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    16:48:21    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    16:48:21    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    16:48:21    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    16:48:21    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    16:48:21    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    16:48:21    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    16:48:21    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:98)
    16:48:21    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:64)
    16:48:21    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    16:48:21    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    16:48:21    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    16:48:21    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    16:48:21    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    16:48:21    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    16:48:21    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    16:48:21    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    16:48:21    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    16:48:21 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.3.1:sonar failed: null value
    16:48:21    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
    16:48:21    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    16:48:21    ... 27 more
    16:48:21 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null value
    16:48:21    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:204)
    16:48:21    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.entryOf(ImmutableMap.java:139)
    16:48:21    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.put(ImmutableMap.java:178)
    16:48:21    at com.google.common.collect.Maps.fromProperties(Maps.java:594)
    16:48:21    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.(Batch.java:50)
    16:48:21    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.(Batch.java:38)
    16:48:21    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch$Builder.build(Batch.java:148)
    16:48:21    at org.sonar.maven3.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:133)
    16:48:21    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    16:48:21    ... 28 more
    16:48:21 Sending e-mails to: *****
    16:48:21 channel stopped
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that work for me:

1) add pre -build step - build maven project with goals **celan install**

2) main build step is the same

```
org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-maven3-plugin:3.3.1:sonar -P sonar -X
```